# 'conda list' shows package but anaconda navigator does not

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

When I type conda list into Windows command I can see

> pyswarm    0.6      pip

but when I search for pyswarm in my root environment it doesn't show up. Assuming that only packages in my anaconda list can be imported in PyCharm (*false, see comment*), I want pyswarm to show up in my list in root (3.6)

I have tried (pip uninstall pyswarm after each failed attempt)

> pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple pyswarm ([from here](https://anaconda.org/pypi/pyswarm))
>
> pip install --upgrade pyswarm ([from here](http://pythonhosted.org/pyswarm/))
>
> activate root (enter) --- pip install --upgrade swarm

My fix was to just <strike>use Jupyter</strike> copy the pso.py library into my PyCharm project

Thoughts:

- The first install attempt is for a 2.7 package. My root is 3.6
- There is a [Git repo](https://github.com/tisimst/pyswarm/issues), but I believe this is a more appropriate platform for this Q

Comment: It turns out that you don't need the package to show up in the navigator for PyCharm to recognize it. I was able to import pyswarm into my project anyways and it ran just dandy

Answer (score 0):

It will only show anaconda site-packages folder where all libraries are installed. You can't directly see in program files like normal software. 
Anaconda is listing because it found in site-packages. Use any IDE (ex:PyCharm or simple windows cmd ) to check whether you able to import or not.

> Import package-name

Comment: Hey Ramineni, what do you mean by "all libraries". Wouldn't downloading pyswarm via pip download the library and therefore should show up in my navigator? If I look in site-packages in explorer I can find the pyswarm folder